# An Xcode warning in swift 5 on UIApplicationMain

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, warnings

In my project there is a main.swift file, with this code in it:

```
UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc,
                  UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
                    .bindMemory(
                        to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self,
                        capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc)),
                  NSStringFromClass(Application.self),
                  NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)
```

The warning is:

"'UIApplicationMain' is deprecated: Use the overload of UIApplicationMain where the type of the second parameter is UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer?>, which is the same as the type of CommandLine.unsafeArgv."

Can anyone elaborate what this warning is saying and give an example of a way to do what it suggests?

Much Appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't verified this answer but it's to long for a comment.

> which is the same as the type of CommandLine.unsafeArgv."

This seems to imply that you can use `CommandLine.unsafeArgv` directly. i.e.

```
UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc,
                  CommandLine.unsafeArgv,
                  NSStringFromClass(Application.self),
                  NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
```

Even if not, the return type of your `bind` is `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>` which is subtly different from what is expected. The generic type for the outer `UnsafeMutablePointer` is expected to be optional. i.e. `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>`

Comment: Yes, that compiles without errors or warnings.

Comment: @MartinR But does it run :)

Comment: @MartinR I guess it must run since it's been accepted.

Comment: @JeremyP It runs & it runs without errors or warnings. Thanks!